# Vibration causing lag on OnePlus 6

Tags: unity, c#, android

has anyone experienced vibration causing lag on OnePlus 6 (or other device)? I'm developing a mobile game on unity and lately I have been Integrating Nice Vibrations to our game which is basically a wrapper for both Android and iOS vibration.

Basically whenever vibrations become too rapid, like 10 vibration patterns/second , my OP6 drops framerate from 60 to 20.
This lagging happens with any game that uses a lot vibration so it can't be caused by any bug in our codebase.

Has anyone else faced similar behaviour and managed to fix it?

Comment: I know it's been a while. We are experiencing the same issue with Nice Vibrations and OpePlus (and some Xiaomi phones).
Have you managed the problem?
Thanks